# Best tools to hold a wireless mic in place

Tags: wireless, clips

I have a fun gig providing sound for a Free Theater program. The guys put on a great production at a community center for 5-6 weeks in the Spring and Fall. I've been learning a lot about sound design and live audio production. The actors ultimately put on their wirelesses as they get in and out of costume. But the hair pins are cutting into their wires and causing havoc!  Bobby pins are the worst offenders. We have approved some gentler hair pins but they've managed to have them cut into the wire as well.  Is anyone aware of any specialized pins that actors can wear to hold mics in their hair that doesn't chew up the wire?  We have tie clips that came with the mics but nothing for the hair.

We do have some over the ear mics that would be ideal in some cases but last year an actor still had to use a hair pin to help hide the wire and that one also cut into the wire.

Comment: Could you post a link for the wireless mic in question? 

Comment: @Brendan Sure! http://www.sennheiserusa.com/professional-lavalier-microphone-lapel-microphone-ME-4-005020  

Answer (score 2):

Just off the top of my head, another possible way to do it would be to thread the lav wire through an elastic band, twist the band so it grips the wire, and then use hair pins to clips a loop of the elastic band to the hair.

Just might be less troublesome than a tape/hair situation.

Answer (score 1):

Have the actors use the pins if they have to, but use something around the wire to protect it from the pin.  Electrical tape should do.

I've never seen special pins before, but perhaps they exist. How many are the actors using?  They really only need one or two - the rest of the wire can be attached with surgical tape to the skin and that's much kinder to wires.  In fact, when I've worn one I used tape only - as long as the wire is taped to the back of the neck then firmly tape to the hairline you're good. I get the impression the actors may be overdoing it with the pins if the wires are getting mangled.

Here is surg tape I like...

http://www.amazon.com/3M-Transpore-Tape-10-Box/dp/B000MILZ8G/ref=sr_1_10?ie=UTF8&qid=1329628831&sr=8-10

edit: http://livedesignonline.com/gear/0701-wireless-mics-toolkit/ she mentions a couple other 3m tapes.  Also I like her suggestion for an over the ear position for baldies ;).  I found this when I searching for methods I haven't tried yet.

Comment: also, I'll second @Brenden on the link for the mic.  I was assuming a mini lav.  Maybe it is one of the larger guys.